# Array salvando apenas o último valor inserido (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Eu tenho um script que captura todos os processos da máquina, usando a biblioteca `PSUTIL`, Porém ao colocar dentro de um array ele só está gravando na memória o último valor, e não todos os valores.

**OBS:** *Preciso dos valores dentro de um array para fazer comparações*

Se alguém identificar o erro, será de grande ajuda :)

```
import psutil, datetime

cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()
process = []

for pid in psutil.pids():

    try:
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        name = p.name()  # execute internal routine once collecting multiple info
        time = p.cpu_times()  # return cached value
        mem_percent = p.memory_percent(memtype="rss") # return cached value
        cpu_percent = p.cpu_percent(interval=1) / cpu_count # return cached value
        create_time = p.create_time()  # return cached value
        pid = p.ppid()  # return cached value
        status = p.status()  # return cached value
    except: continue

    process = [''+str(pid)+'',''+str(name)+'',''+str(cpu_percent)+'',''+str(mem_percent)+'',''+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))+'',''+str(time)+'',''+str(status)+'']

for i in range(len(process)):
    print(process[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escrevendo assim: `process = [` esta sobrescrevendo o array, ou seja, a cada vez que executa essa linha, é criado o array com um elemento, e no seu caso exibe só o último. Para adicionar um novo elemento ao array use `append`:

```
process.append( [''+str(pid)+'',''+str(name)+'',''+str(cpu_percent)+'',''+str(mem_percent)+'',''+str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(create_time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))+'',''+str(time)+'',''+str(status)+''])
```

Assim estará adicionando um item ao final do array.

Comment: Muito obrigado!